# Connecting to Gmail from EC2

Tags: php, function, amazon-ec2, gmail

I'm having an issue that is made worse by a deadline to get it working hanging over my head.  The following code has been running successfully on my old web server.  When moving it to amazon EC2 however it causes the page it is called on to not open beyond it (i.e. it's not working).  I have made sure that port 993 is open on EC2 but as I'm new to server setup I may be missing something:

```
function downloadData($emailAddress, $reportUrl, $reportType)
{
    $result = "error";
    // DOWNLOAD DATA
    // the max time allows for the email to download
    set_time_limit(3000);

    // connect to gmail with your credentials
    $hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
    $username = $emailAddress; # e.g somebody@gmail.com
    $password = '*************';


    // try to connect
    $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot download information: ' . imap_last_error());


    /* get all new emails. If set to 'ALL' instead 
     * of 'NEW' retrieves all the emails, but can be 
     * resource intensive, so the following variable, 
     * $max_emails, puts the limit on the number of emails downloaded.
     * 
     */
    $emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

    // useful only if the above search is set to 'ALL'
    $max_emails = 5;


    // if any emails found, iterate through each email
    if($emails)
        {
            $count = 1;

            // put the newest emails on top
            rsort($emails);

            // for every email...
            foreach($emails as $email_number) 
                {
                    // get information specific to this email
                    $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);

                    // get mail message
                    $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);

                    // get mail structure
                    $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $email_number);

                    $attachments = array();

                    // if any attachments found...
                    if(isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts)) 
                        {
                          for($i = 0; $i < count($structure->parts); $i++) 
                            {
                                $attachments[$i] = array(
                                    'is_attachment' => false,
                                    'filename' => '',
                                    'name' => '',
                                    'attachment' => ''
                                    );

                            if($structure->parts[$i]->ifdparameters) 
                                {
                                    foreach($structure->parts[$i]->dparameters as $object) 
                                        {
                                            if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename') 
                                                {
                                                    $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                                                    $attachments[$i]['filename'] = $object->value;
                                                }
                                        }
                                }

                            if($structure->parts[$i]->ifparameters) 
                                {
                                    foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parameters as $object) 
                                        {
                                            if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') 
                                                {
                                                    $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                                                    $attachments[$i]['name'] = $object->value;
                                                }
                                        }
                                }

                            if($attachments[$i]['is_attachment']) 
                                {
                                    $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, $i+1);

                                    // 4 = QUOTED-PRINTABLE encoding
                                    if($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 3) 
                                        { 
                                            $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = base64_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                                        }
                                    // 3 = BASE64 encoding
                                    elseif($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 4) 
                                        { 
                                            $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                                        }
                                                //imap_delete($inbox,$email_number);
                                                imap_mail_move($inbox, $email_number,'[Gmail]/Bin');
                                        }
                                 }
                          }

                     // iterate through each attachment and save it
                     foreach($attachments as $attachment)
                        {
                            if($attachment['is_attachment'] == 1)
                                {
                                    // SCAN REPORT SET OUTSIDE OF FUNCTION
                                    $filename = $reportUrl;
                                    if(empty($filename)) $filename = $attachment['filename'];
                                    if(empty($filename)) $filename = time() . ".dat";

                                    /* prefix the email number to the filename in case two emails
                                    * have the attachment with the same file name.
                                    */
                                    $fp = fopen($filename, "w+");
                                    fwrite($fp, $attachment['attachment']);
                                    fclose($fp);
                                    $result = "success";
                                 }

                        }
                    if($count++ >= $max_emails) break;
                }
        } 
    // close the connection
    imap_close($inbox,CL_EXPUNGE);
    return $result;
}
```

though no error comes up as such (the page is just not loading from where the function is called) the console is returning this error:  500 (Internal Server Error)

Any suggestions what I may be missing?

edit:
It seems that the page errors only when the following pieces of code are included in the function:

```
        // try to connect
    $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot download information: ' . imap_last_error());

    // close the connection
    imap_close($inbox,CL_EXPUNGE);
```

suggesting to me that the issue is the port though according to my ec2 security group the correct port (993) is open.  is there any other ports that should be open in a process like this?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: sorry, I don't think I was clear enough.  There is no error message, the function being used in the page doesn't do anything but any code after its being called is not being read either so it ends up being a half loaded page as in only the code prior to the function being used.

Comment: console is getting this error: 500 (Internal Server Error) but only when the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that EC2 is not on VPC ! When an EC2 instance is inside a VPC ; it needs special configuration for it to connect to internet ( via NAT instance etc ).

I feel first test you should do is do "ssh on your EC2 instance" and then from there try to check if you can access google on port 993.. You could try to ping on imap.google.com

Comment: you might be on to something with that.  I tried to ping imap.google.com but got 'ping: unknown host imap.google.com' though there is no VPC id assigned to the instance

Comment: looks like your EC2 instance is behind a VPC. Check your EC2 details ; you will see "VPC-id" if it is behind a VPC. So, easier solution could be that you move your EC2 outisde VPC. The problem is very basic right now which is that your EC2 instance is not connected to external internet

Comment: there is no VPC id assigned to the instance

Comment: damn it!  that got me too.  yeah, I'm getting a response.